# How to check through command line whether my internet connection is running, and to connect if not running

Tags: windows, networking, batch-file

I have a mobile broadband dongle with a little issue. As soon as the downloaded data reaches 430 MB, the internet connection gets disconnected automatically. May be that's some kind of limit set by the network provider. 
Can I have some batch file running in the background that would periodically check if the internet connection is running, and if it is not running then connect it.
I am using windows 7.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
set "con_name=name_of_your_WAN_connection"
:check
rasdial| findstr /C:"%con_name%" >NUL
if errorlevel 1 rasdial "%con_name%"
timeout /T 60 >NUL
goto check
```

This script check for established WAN connection every single minute. If not established, dial it.

Answer (score -1):

```
netsh wlan CONNECT ssid=SSID HERE name=NETWORK NAME HERE
```

This works in Windows 7 to connect to a single network in batch. HOWEVER if you go to wireless network properties you can set it to automatically connect to the network.

Otherwise if that does not work you would have to use a batch with the commands 
netsh wlan .... as suggested above along with the ping of google and a if else statement.

That is all I know for now, hope this helps.

Answer (score -2):

To Check whether internet connection is working or not ,

At a command prompt type `'ping google.com'` and `press ENTER.` Stop pinging by pressing `CTRL+C.`

For Connecting to Internet,

http://www.ghacks.net/2009/04/14/connect-to-a-wireless-network-via-command-line/